# Handle user login

Tags: android

How to handle this :-
"Now once user login into the app he doesn’t need to login again. If he launches the app after a successful login he will be redirected to the welcome screen directly"

Please help

Comment: SO is not used for people to tell you how to do your project. It is to answer a question that you are having difficulties with.

Comment: Can you please share complete code for logged in and stay logged in until user click on logged out button. Please do share it on- nikhiljain112@gmail.com

Comment: I have to develop android application like this-

The user will input login credentials (Hardcoded of your choice) and submit.
The app will check for validation.If the inputs are right then he will be redirected to welcome screen.
Now once user login into the app he doesn’t need to login again. If he launches the app after a successful login he will be redirected to the welcome screen directly.

Answer (score 1):

you should save logged in user data in SharedPreferences after successfull login.

```
//save login data
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = mContext.getSharedPreferences("datas",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
spe.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
spe.commit();
```

and load login data from SharedPreferences where you want to check if user logged in or not.

```
//Load login data
SharedPreferences sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences("datas",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sp.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false)==true) {
//user is logged in
        } else {
//user is not logged in
        }
```

More about SharedPrefences on android:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Use local storage to keep informations about user is logged on, check it after application start and navigate him to correct activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store login details..try following..

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);
int number = sharedPref.getInt("isLogged", 0);
if(number == 0) {
    //Open the login activity and set this so that next it value is 1 then this condition will be false.
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
    prefEditor.putInt("isLogged",1);
    prefEditor.commit();
} else {
       //Open this Welcome Screen activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store in Shared Preferences if the user has been successfully logged in. You can also add another shared preference to set the automatic login expiry. But also make sure to verify with server for every launch.